# Best way to store json keyfile for GCP functions serverless deployment with Github actions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, github-actions, serverless-framework

I use `serveless` & `Github actions` to deploy GCP functions.

serveless.ylm

```yaml
service: serverless-test

provider:
  name: google
  runtime: go113
  project: my-gcp-project
  credentials: ./gcp_keyfile_serverless.json

frameworkVersion: '2'

plugins:
  - serverless-google-cloudfunctions

package:
  exclude:
    - .gitignore
    - .git/**

functions:
  hello-world:
    handler: Hello
    events:
      - http: path
```

deploy_gcp_go.yml

```yaml
name: Deploy master branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - name: serverless deploy
      uses: serverless/github-action@master
      with:
        args: deploy
      env:
        SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY: ${{secrets.SERVERLESS_SECRET_KEY}}
```

Is there a way to **not store** the `gcp_keyfile_serverless.json` file directly in the Github repo? (used in the `serverless.yml` file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a build step, which decrypts an encrypted `*.json` with [Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/security-key-management).

Or here's another one [example](https://www.codegram.com/blog/a-github-actions-workflow-to-deploy-to-google-cloud-using-serverless-framework/), doing about the same, but with `pgp`.